# QtXml linking issue OSX file not found for architecture x86_64 (but file IS x86_64)

Tags: qt, clang, linker-errors, qtxml

I'm trying to compile a Qt creator project that uses QtXml, and everything is happy except for the fact that apparently QtXml is not the right format. The linking flags are:

```
-F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -L../../../lib/ -lutils -framework QtTest -framework IOKit -framework Security -framework ApplicationServices -framework QtCore -framework QtGui
```

and then the linker complains with

```
ld: file not found: QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml for architecture x86_64
```

BUT file gives me:

```
file /Library/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml
/Library/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

So I'm confused, the file is there, seems to be the right architecture, but no banana.

does anyone know what's going on ?

thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

got it, I was compiing with Clang (LLVM) should've compiled with gcc (probably the Mach-O should've tipped me off, could anyone elaborate on this ?)

J